# What is the correct use of "at the age of" or similar for describing a group of people?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Recently, for a scientific publication, I wrote something like the following:

> The sample consisted of all students at the age of 13 years or older.

However, I received this back from the language check changed into the following:

> The sample consisted of all students who were 13 years of age or older.

While I see that the second versions indeed sounds a little nicer, I was wondering if the first version would be correct from a grammatical point of view when it is used for describing a group of people as opposed to, say, for describing the age of a person at which an event has occured.

Can I use "at the age of" for describing a group of people? If not, would anyone able to clarify the correct use of this phrase?

Comment: It's technically correct (other than the misplaced "all") but sounds awkward.

Comment: The problem here is the preposition "at".  You might have written "aged 13 or older" and that would be idiomatic.  In a scientific paper, however, you don't say "or older".  Since you know all their ages, you have to be accurate: from 13 to 67 years of age.

Comment: @Hot Licks: That was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a scientific paper, if you wanted to include the number, you could also say "consisted of all students who were 13 years of age or older (n=158)."

A phrase often used to describe an age group is [cohort](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cohort):

> (definition 6)
>   a group of persons sharing a particular statistical or demographic characteristic: *the cohort of all children born in 1980*

Here is a picture using "age cohort" to illustrate.

[image: age cohort image]

So I might rewrite the sentence as:

> The sample consisted of all students (n=158) in the age cohort over 13.

Comment: Thank you, @rajah9. Please also see my comment on the OP. The "of 158 all students" was a typo.

Comment: I have edited out the parts referring to the typo. Thank you for accepting the answer.